# MySQL get record count by hour, even the hours with no records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I want to query for the average of the column values in a table by hour for the past 24 hours. I'm having trouble displaying results even for the hours with no records (in these cases, I should print an average of 0)

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT HOUR(time), AVG(score) FROM place_rvw WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND place_id = 1 ORDER BY HOUR(time);
```

Right now (12 AM), for example, the only records I have is for 9PM and 10PM. Thus, there are only two rows in the result. I want it to have 24 rows (representing each of the past 24 hours) and simply display an average of 0 if an hour has no records.

Any form of help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit
I tried the query below like what Stephan suggested, but it still displays the same result. The ideal result should have all 24 rows representing each hour. Any suggestions?

```
  SELECT za_hours.za_hour as hour, AVG(IFNULL(score,0)) as average_score
  FROM (
  SELECT 0 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 1 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 3 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 4 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 5 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 6 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 7 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 8 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 9 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 10 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 11 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 12 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 13 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 14 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 15 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 16 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 17 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 18 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 19 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 20 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 21 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 22 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 23 as za_hour
) za_hours
LEFT JOIN place_rvw 
  ON za_hours.za_hour = HOUR(time)
  AND
  time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  AND place_id = 1 
GROUP BY
  za_hours.za_hour
ORDER BY za_hours.za_hour
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a table with 24 rows, one for each for a hour.

2) Make a left outter join with your table.

The solution WORKS as show in this:
[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91df83/5)

You are still not getting results due to the filtering

Comment: Yeah, I tried this one as what Stephan suggested but it displayed the same result. The IFNULL function to set 0 values didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I just added the where clause conditions to the LEFT JOIN part (see my post edit).

Comment: I'll take that as my answer was the accepted one ;p

Answer (score 1):

You need something like :

```
SELECT 
  za_hours.za_hour, 
  AVG(IFNULL(score,0)) 
FROM (
  SELECT 0 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 1 as za_hour
  ...
  SELECT 23 as za_hour
) za_hours
LEFT JOIN place_rvw 
  ON za_hours.za_hour = HOUR(time)
WHERE 
  time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  AND place_id = 1 
GROUP BY
  za_hours.za_hour
ORDER BY za_hours.za_hour
```

`za_hours` is a tmp table containing all the hours (0,1.. 24) so that when you have no records for a certain hour you will still have results (even though they will be zero)

Comment: Thanks! This could be the solution. But may I ask how I can determine the past 24 hours in that temp table? For example, the hour right NOW is 2AM. Thus, I should just include 3AM (yesterday) up until this hour.

Comment: @galibee in the temp table you will always have 24 hours ... the restriction in time is made by putting the conditions on `time` column which you already have `time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY `

Comment: Got it and I thought it'd work but it still displays the same result.

Comment: Found the solution. I just placed the conditions in the where clause to the LEFT JOIN part (check my post edit). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE statement is keeping it from displaying the rows that contain 0. Use an OR in your WHERE statement to do something like: OR time = 0

Comment: the rows don't contain 0, there is no row for that time period.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood that part.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Reason why I added the clause AND place_id = 1 is because I only want to display results having that foreign key. Replacing AND with OR will generate incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
WHERE 
  time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  AND place_id = 1
```

**to this:**

```
WHERE 
  (time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  or time is null)
  AND place_id = 1
```