# Count all records in last 12 hours on hourly basis in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to count records hourly in last 12 hours from my mysql table.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834899/mysql-get-record-count-by-hour-even-the-hours-with-no-records) but my problem is, let say currently it's January 7 2016, 9 AM then i would like to count records from 7th Jan 9AM to Jan 6th 9PM.
My table structure is as following:

```
Table name :: cebod_cdr

id|userid|starting_date|total_duration
1 | 17 | 2016-01-07 09:00:00 | 12
2 | 17 | 2016-01-07 07:30:24 | 45
3 | 17 | 2016-01-07 01:12:21 | 5
4 | 17 | 2016-01-06 10:30:00 | 18
5 | 17 | 2016-01-06 10:45:00 | 25
```

Example output

```
hour | calls
9AM | 1
8AM | 0
7AM | 1
6AM | 0
5AM | 0
4AM | 0
3AM | 0
2AM | 0
1AM | 1
12AM | 0
11PM | 0
10PM | 2
```

If there is any problem in displaying hours in desired format(1-12), i can display it in some other format like 24 hours format etc.

Comment: Both of the queries in the answers below will get you the resuls. If you want to run this query on an hourly basis - you should setup a cron job.

Comment: No. It's showing records only when there is a data whereas i want to display results even when there is no record in past 12 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT HOUR(starting_date) AS Hour, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM cebod_cdr
WHERE starting_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(starting_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    date_format(dh.starting_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as hour,
    COUNT(md.id) AS count
FROM
    cebod_cdr dh 
    LEFT JOIN cebod_cdr md ON dh.starting_date = DATE_FORMAT(md.starting_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
WHERE dh.starting_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
    AND dh.starting_date <  NOW()
GROUP BY dh.starting_date
ORDER BY dh.starting_date
```

Comment: It's showing records only when there is a data whereas i want to display results even when there is no record in past 12 hours.

Comment: Well that completely changes some parts of the query :) I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer as below:

```
    SELECT za_hours.za_hour as hour, COUNT(id) as calls 
    FROM ( 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 7 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 9 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 10 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 11 HOUR as za_hour UNION 
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR as za_hour ) 
    za_hours 
    LEFT JOIN 
    cebod_cdr 
    ON DATE_FORMAT(za_hours.za_hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:') = DATE_FORMAT(starting_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:') 
    AND starting_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
    GROUP BY za_hours.za_hour 
    ORDER BY za_hours.za_hour
```

Please suggest if i can improve this query.